# Can website detect if I’m using chrome remote desktop?

Tags: chrome, remote-desktop

I was wondering if the website can detect the remote operation of my PC while I’m visiting.

For example;
I visit one website and click here and there while using  my laptop for controlling my desktop using chrome remote desktop.
Can the website find out that I’m remote controlling?

Comment: No. There is no way to tell who is using the browser on the client-side.

Answer (score 3):

No. They will be able to see user agent from the remote desktop, not from your actual computer you are connecting remote desktop to.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The chrome browser http request and the Chrome RDP session are two separate things.

The browser might send the browser user agent in the header but not the way you are connected to your device.

Answer (score -2):

RDP sessions usually do have a different color depth. Also whatever system you are using in the end for accessing the website might have a distinct fingerprint (device, IP ...) compared to the system which you use for initiating the RDP session